# Element trigger click event doesn't work with ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I need to pass a click event from the controller so I used this code:

```js
angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('#cal')).triggerHandler('click');
```

In my browser it works when put ionic serve but it didn't work on mobile

Comment: `triggerHandler` is available to 1.3 onwards.below it use 'trigger'

Comment: but it does n't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write in this way in your controller.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {

        angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('#cal')).triggerHandler('click');

        //OR

        angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('#cal')).trigger('click');

});
```

Comment: angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('#cal')).triggerHandler('click'); this also work in some devices case is gamsung device thanks for your answer